# How to disable soft returns in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do you disable soft returns in emacs?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LongLines

> By default, soft returns are
>   automatically inserted as you edit, to
>   keep your text wrapped. If you do not
>   want this effect, set
>   ‘longlines-auto-wrap’ to ‘nil’. You
>   can still type ‘M-q’, or use any of
>   the other fill commands, to fill text
>   using soft returns (see
>   FillParagraph.)

Answer (score 2):

Aha! [M-x toggle-truncate-lines] is what I was looking for.

Thanks for the help though.